# Нужна помощь с меняющимся задним фоном в unity2d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно сделать меняющийся задний фон для игры в unity2d. Есть 6 картинок , как мне сделать так , чтобы они плавно переключались допустим каждые 5-10 секунд ? Спасибо за отведенное мне время.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Держите скрипт:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Class1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SpriteRenderer[] renderers;
    public float speed;
    private float a;
    private int i, l;
    private void Start()
    {
        l = renderers.Length - 1;
        for (int e = 1; e < l + 1; e++) renderers[e].color -= new Color(0, 0, 0, renderers[e].color.a);
    }
    private int getI(int v)
    {
        if (v < l) return v + 1;
        else return 0;
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (a < 254)
        {
            a += speed;
            renderers[i].color -= new Color(0, 0, 0, speed / 255f);
            renderers[getI(i)].color += new Color(0, 0, 0, speed / 255f);
        }
        else
        {
            if (i < l) i++;
            else i = 0;
            a = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Создайте пустой объект и переместите скрипт на него. В поле renderers поместите массив спрайтов заднего фона (количество не ограниченно).

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Прошу прощения , а как мне изменить время переключения картинок ?

Comment: Я изменил ответ, ввел переменную скорости. Можете изменять этот параметр, пока не получите, что хотите. :)

Comment: Спасибо огромное , сейчас буду пробовать

Comment: Всегда рад помочь

Comment: Еще раз прошу прощения, добавил компонент sprite renderer и картинки не отображаются

Comment: (https://imgur.com/a/KWl4mwF)

Comment: Увидел , как мне сделать картинки на весь экран ?

Comment: Вы положили объект с фоном в canvas. На нем отображаются только элементы UI (кнопки и дизайн). Вытащите из него объекты с фоном и растяните так, чтобы они попадали в камеру.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное !

Comment: Изменяйте параметр Scale у объектов